# Ethernet Network dropping with fresh Archlinux and RTL8125 2.5GbE

Tags: linux, arch-linux, networkmanager

I've installed a new OS on my machine which is a pure Arch Linux. Everything works well, but I have difficulties to find out what is going on with my Ethernet.

On the same machine, I have PopOS working flawlessly.

The symptoms are the following:

- With neovim I need to do `:PlugUpdate8` to get the update through otherwise it is loosing connection (Like explains there: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/502)
- Still with neovim, when tree-sitter try to downloads what it needs, it never works. I always have an error message telling me to check my Network.

While this look like only neovim. I realize that I was loosing the connection and could not access any sites.

At one point other device connected to the same Switch lost the connection too.

I remember having this issue the first time I install this computer. A BIOS update at the time fixed the issue.

I checked those informations:

```
lspci | grep -i net
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller (rev 05)
```

```
sudo dmesg |grep r8169
[ 8139.291767] libphy: r8169: probed
[ 8139.291914] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth0: RTL8125B, b4:2e:99:f5:23:7a, XID 641, IRQ 92
[ 8139.291916] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[ 8139.572758] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eno1: renamed from eth0
[ 8139.703857] RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY r8169-0-500:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-500:00, irq=MAC)
[ 8139.870671] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 8143.010760] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eno1: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
```

Which looks ok...

Could someone helping to debug my issue?

Answer (score 0):

After some bandwidth check and some debugging. I did not find anything...

Until I realize that the error on the browser relates to DNS. I am behind AdGuard installed on my local NAS.

Changing the D.N.S. to 1.1.1.1 solved the issue...

So, it is finally not Linux related. I will continue debugging my issue on AdGuard.